# Access the DEB files contained in the ISO installation image

Tags: iso, deb, extract

I have to access the entire archive of DEB files contained in the ISO installation image, I have just mounted the ISO image and after the "casper/filesystem.squashfs" file-system...

```
sudo mkdir /media/iso
sudo mount -o loop /home/fabio/Desktop/ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso /media/iso/
sudo mkdir /media/casper
sudo mount -t squashfs /media/iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs /media/casper/
```

but any DEB searching...

```
sudo find /media/casper/ -type f -name "*.deb"
```

returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searches I discover that the installation ISO contain the DEB files in extracted state, so no DEB file but only Installed Packages. ;)

Comment: IIRC debs must be be in `/pool` or just `/media/pool`.

Comment: I can't find any `/pool` or `/media/pool` directories. Anyway, I'm thinking to try to add the mounted ISO image as a CD repository and see if so I can obtain some extra results. Any help is REALLY appreciated... ;)

Comment: Since you mounted the ISO in `/media/iso/`, pool must be in that folder. Previously, I misread that you mounted the ISO in `/media`. You can treat `/media/iso` as the root of the mounted image, i.e. `/media/iso/` is the `/` of ISO.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I found 43 DEB files under the `/mnt/iso/pool` folder. Now I'm lloking for a simple and effective method to can access to the entire ISO packages repository, via command-line, but this could be subject for a new "Question"! ;)